# Javascript Expand/Collapse

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm quite new to Javascript.
I've been trying to figure this one out but can't seem to.
So my question is...

**What do I need to do in the code so that when you have 'one' open and when you click 'two', the content below 'one' collapses?**

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Help!</title>

</head>
<body>

<div>
<a href="#" id="1" class="title" name="1">one</a>
</div> 
<div id="workdiv1" class="workdiv" style="display:none">content 1
</div> 
</div> 

<div class="storybottom">
<a href="#" id="2" class="title" name="2">two</a>
</div> 
<div id="workdiv2" class="workdiv" style="display:none">content 2
</div> 
</div> 

<div class="storybottom">
<a href="#" id="3" class="title" name="3">three</a>
</div> 
<div id="workdiv3" class="workdiv" style="display:none">content 3
</div> 
</div> 

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#work').hide(); 

        $('a.title').click(function() { 
            var id = $(this).attr('id'); 
            $('#workdiv' + id).toggle(150); 
            return false; 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/kSQfy/

Comment: also, look into jquery ui, you can use an accordion for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('a.title').click(function(){
      var target = $(this).closest('div').next('div');
      var mode = target.is(':visible');
      target.siblings('div.workdiv').hide();
      if(!mode) target.show(); else target.hide();
 });
```

Like this?

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to close the ones that were previous open.My goal is to have this system where the content expands and collapses with animation and also when something different is selected the previous content collapses. Like an accordion!

Comment: @user1413528 Updated. You can add your animation settings in the `hide()/show()` functions.

Comment: Hi grigore, first of all thanks alot! i wrote at the bottom too butis it possible to embed a code so that when you click on the same "header", it closes? e.g. when "one" is open and click it again, it collapses..?

Comment: thank you so much! works like a charm. I noticed that I could replace **target.siblings('div.workdiv').hide();** with **$('div.workdiv').hide();** as well. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/kSQfy/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.title').click(function() {
        var correspondingDiv = $(this).parent().next('div');

        if (!correspondingDiv.is(':hidden')) {
            return;
        }

        // hide other divs
        $('.workdiv').hide(150);

        // show this one
        correspondingDiv.toggle(150);
    }); 
}); ​
```

Comment: Hi jbabey, this looks very close but is it possible to embed a code so that when you click on the same "header", it closes? e.g. when "one" is open and click it again, it collapses..?

Comment: @davidgogh everything you'd need to do that is already there, we're not here to do the work for you ;)